# data.table Splitting column into multiple columns based on two conditions

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation

I want to split `Y` column of the following `data.table` into two columns based on `/` or `-`.

```
df1 <- 
  structure(list(Y = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6/7", "8-10")), 
            .Names = "Y", row.names = c(NA, -7L)
            , class = "data.frame"
            )
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(df1)
dt1[ , c("Y1", "Y2") := tstrsplit(Y, "/", fixed = TRUE)]
dt1
      Y   Y1 Y2
1:    1    1 NA
2:    2    2 NA
3:    3    3 NA
4:    4    4 NA
5:    5    5 NA
6:  6/7    6  7
7: 8-10 8-10 NA
```

**Required**

The required result is

```
      Y   Y1
1:    1    1
2:    2    2
3:    3    3
4:    4    4
5:    5    5
6:  6/7    6
7: 8-10    8
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just select the first number, i.e.

```
library(data.table)
dt1[, Y1 := as.integer(gsub('[[:punct:]].*', '', Y))]
dt1
#      Y Y1
#1:    1  1
#2:    2  2
#3:    3  3
#4:    4  4
#5:    5  5
#6:  6/7  6
#7: 8-10  8
```

Comment: How to make final column numeric?

Comment: You can wrap `gsub` to `as.numeric`. I updated my answer

Comment: `as.integer` may be more efficient

Comment: @akrun yes indeed